# How to instruct apt-get and/or synaptic to install from source code?

Tags: apt, synaptic

As I asked in the title, I would like to know how to setup Synaptic or how to instruct `apt-get to install/upgrade` software exclusively from source. I mean, apt-get/synaptic install only pre-compiled packets. I would like to setup the "building all" like Portage in Gentoo. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: You can get the source for a package with `apt-get source packagename` but building it and installing are separate steps

Comment: Warren, can you explain briefly these steps, please? at least command(s) examples. Thanks.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Not a duplicate, OP is asking about compiling packages from source, not about building Ubuntu from source.

Comment: @BasharatSial Question: "I would like to setup the "building all" like Portage in Gentoo." Answer: "apt-build world" Seems very much like a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `apt-build`

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/apt-build.1.html

See also [How to build all my installed package from sources?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29856/build-ubuntu-from-source-for-speed)

Building from source is, IMO over rated. See :

http://funroll-loops.info/

(yes I am a long time gentoo user as well)

And

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system

And

http://biodegradablegeek.com/2008/12/gentoo-sucks-ubuntu-doesnt/

Honestly, again IMO, if you want to do all this, I highly suggest you use gentoo.

Answer (score 3):

Apt-get doesn't work like BSD ports or Gentoo portage.  You can apt-get source and debuild all of them individually, but it's not easily automate-able or built-in.

You could theoretically script mirroring a source repo, building a dependency chain, starting at the root, and building each package... but generally for the target user-base of Ubuntu, it's not worth it.