# Xara LX won't launch in 13.10

Tags: 13.10

I installed the package 'xaralx' via apt-get on Xubuntu 13.10 Saucy 64-bit and I get this when I type in "xaralx" at the command prompt:

```
xaralx: relocation error: xaralx: symbol _ZTV19wxGnomePrintFactory, version WXU_2.8 not defined in file libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0 with link time reference
```

I uninstalled xaralx and installed xaralx:i386 and I get the same error.

My system started out with 12.04 LTS and I upgraded it all the way up to 13.10, so that might have something to do with it.

Comment: I have the same problem. I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and the upgrade apparently broke Xara LX. I was using it all the time, it worked just fine with 13.04.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question because this package **is part of the software center**. I think that the packages in the software center should install as expected and else there should be a solution here.

Comment: @don.joey are you certain that the problem still exists?

Comment: @guntbert This problem still exists. I tried the install through the software center yesterday. Installing using `sudo apt-get install xaralx` does not make a difference. 13.10

Comment: @chaskes can you expand your comment and post it as an answer?

Comment: @don.joey Answer posted.

Answer (score 2):

**Getting `xaralx` to run**

The workaround for this problem is to rebuild the package. But don't worry! This is very easy to do with `apt-build`.

`apt-build` will automatically download the source, resolve the dependencies, build the debian package, and then install the package. The package can then also be removed through `apt-get` as normal.

`apt-build` is not installed by default:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-build
```

The installation will present a few configuration options; accepting the defaults is fine. (For more information on the configuration, see [this answer on building from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29856/how-to-build-all-my-installed-package-from-sources).)

Then:

```
sudo apt-build install xaralx
```

This process will take some time depending on your computer. On my Asus X201E (Celeron 847, 1.10 GHz, 4 GB ram) it took about 30 minutes.

The process will also rebuild some dependent packages: `xaralx-svg`, `xaralx-examples`, and `libxar-dev`, so follow this with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The examples are not installed by default, so you may also want:

```
sudo apt-get install xaralx-examples
```

That's it! `xaralx` can now be launched normally and will start without an error.

Note: If you are on a 64-bit installation, you may see get this error message after `apt-get update`:

```
W: Failed to fetch file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository/dists/apt-build/main/binary-i386/Packages  File not found
```

This is harmless, but you can get rid of it by editing the `apt-build` source list. (See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394653/ubuntu-64-bit-failed-to-fetch-file-binary-i386-packages-error-while-updat), but please note that you only need to change `apt-build.list`. *No* changes are needed in the standard `sources.list`).

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-build.list
```

Change

```
deb file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository apt-build main
```

to:

```
deb [arch=amd64] file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository apt-build main
```

**Background information**

This problem is the result of a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poedit/+bug/610686) that had been in a previous version of `libwxgtk2.8-xx`.

This affected all packages using `wxWidgets` that had been compiled against any version of `libwxgtk` prior to `2.8.10.1-0ubuntu1`.

Most packages have since been fixed, but some older packages that have not have not had much recent development work, such as `xaralx`, may still have the problem.

The solution is to rebuild the package with updated dependencies.

This was reported [against xaralx](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xaralx/+bug/1247219) and the problem has been fixed upstream in the Debian package. For some reason, however, the Ubuntu package will still install a binary that has not been fixed and will not run.

Comment: Excellent answer. Xara XL compiles fine (4 minutes on my machine :) It does suffer from bugs, though. It is not production ready.

Comment: @don.joey Thanks.It was a lot of work, but I agreed with your reasoning and it turned into a good first foray into learning debian packaging. Note I was careful to say only it will start without error. ;) My x201 may be slow, but it was an Ubuntu preload and has an Ubuntu sticker on it. :)