# Disable Google Chrome warning about 32 bit on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

After upgrading to Chrome 48, i see the message:

*This computer will soon stop receiving Google Chrome updates because this Linux system will no longer be supported*

Is there a way to hide or disable that message?

Edit: I'm not asking about Linux support, i just want to disable the message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This computer will soon stop receiving Google Chrome updates because this Linux system will no longer be supported](http://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/this-computer-will-soon-stop-receiving-google-chrome-updates-because-this-linux)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds That one doesn't talk about hiding the error message, it ask about Linux support.

Comment: You really shouldn't keep using an old Chrome - new security vulnerabilities will be found.

Comment: That's right, but i'm using the newest version `48`, and the next LTS is in April, until then, I'm hoping to find a way to disable that message.

Comment: you are asking us to put you in trouble

Comment: @Edward Torvalds, I respectfully disagree. First of all, the OP is probably wrong when saying _upgrading to Chrome 48_ - as far as I know, what he refers to is **Chromium** and not to **Google Chrome**. But more importantly, from my experience, running even a **very** old version of a web browser means at most missing out on features and possibly seeing web sites not correctly rendered. I have _**never**_ experienced any security risk.

Comment: No worries, I've switched to x64 long time ago, just wan't ready at the time of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are making sens for me, because I am using an old 32 bit Ubuntu without any possibilities of upgrade and chromium don't provide DRM access for my iptv broadcaster.

I agree that this message is really annoying .. it's ok I have understand ... no longer support... stop saying that at each run, i'm not stupid, i can remember that it's an old version....

the simplest solution is :

/usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-infobars

Comment: for permanent change edit /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome with sudo and update last line with : 


  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" --disable-infobars "$@"

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 16.04.7, Xenial, 64 bit, but my workaround works fine for any OS versions. In my case I follow this steps:

1. Download old debian package of Chrome v. 108 from url:
   *https://oldversions.info/down/chrome/108_version/google-chrome_108_amd64.deb*;
2. Uninstall every Chromium or Google Chrome versions, and disable relatives repositories:

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser* google-chrome*
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> sudo apt-get autoclean
> sudo apt-get clean
> sudo apt purge $(COLUMNS=300 dpkg -l | egrep -v '^[hi]i\s' | 
>   awk 'length($1) < 4 && $1 ~ /[a-zA-Z]/ {print($2)}' | tr '\n' ' ')
> ```

3. Go on ~/Downloads folder (or other location where you are donwloaded .deb file in step 1) and type:

> `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome_108_amd64.deb`

```
then wait installation completion;
```

4. create an autorun script, name it *"MySettings.sh"*, and save in your home directory:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> #
> # My personal settings
>
> # Symlink os-release - for Google Chrome "Unsupported OS Warning" patch.
> [ -e /tmp/os-release ] && rm /tmp/os-release
> ln -s /usr/lib/os-release.ori /tmp/os-release
> exit
> ```

5. making previous script operative by creating .desktop launcher in your folder "~/.config/autostart". Edit in that folder a file as "MySettings.desktop", ad save it typing:

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Type=Application
> Name=MySettings
> Name[<your-lang>]=MySettings
> GenericName[<your-lang>]=Impostazioni personali
> Comment=Personal Settings
> Comment[<your-lang>]=Personal Settings
> Icon=/bin/bash
> Exec=/bin/bash /home/<you-user-name>/MySettings.sh
> NoDisplay=true
> NotShowIn=Gnome;Unity;
> ```

don't forget to make it executable:
chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/MySettings.desktop

6. rename original *"os-release"* file:

> sudo mv /usr/lib/os-release /usr/lib/os-release.ori

7. change old os-release file name in new symlink:

> sudo ln -s /tmp/os-release /usr/lib/os-release

8. create new os-release file, with dummy field to "cheat" Chrome, and save it as *"/usr/lib/os-release.mod"*:

> sudo *<your-text-editor>* /usr/lib/os-release.mod

and type in it:

> ```
> NAME="Ubuntu"
> VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
> ID=ubuntu
> ID_LIKE=debian
> PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
> VERSION_ID="22.04"
> HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
> SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
> VERSION_CODENAME=Jammy
> UBUNTU_CODENAME=Jammy
> ```

9. Now you have to *"hacking"* Google Chrome. First, rename launcher:

> sudo mv /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome1

10. now you have to create a new launcher, saving it as "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome". Therefore:

```
sudo <your-text-editor> /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

then type in it:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> #
> # Start Chrome with params and "Unsupported OS Warning" patch.
> # 
>
> # "Unsupported OS Warning patch".
> rm -f /tmp/os-release
> ln -s /usr/lib/os-release.mod /tmp/os-release
> sync
>
> /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome1 --log-level=0 --ash-hide-notifications-for-factory --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT' "$@" &
> disown
>
> # Restore os-release link
> sleep 3
> rm -f /tmp/os-release
> ln -s /usr/lib/os-release.ori /tmp/os-release
> exit
> ```

THAT'ALL !!!

Now you can use Chrome version 108 got rid from every warnig message about missing update or unsupported OS.

Enjoy...