# Why Google Chrome will not be supported?

Tags: google-chrome

Xubuntu was perfect for my laptop, but now after a couple of months when I open Google Chrome, I get the message that Google Chrome will not longer support this Linux version. My version is 14.04.3 LTS (Software &Updates says 14.04.3 Trusty Tahr / beta i386).

Why is it no longer supported?

Which new version can I now use the longest period of time: 14.0.4 64 Bit (how do I know I can install that?) Or 15.10?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/this-computer-will-soon-stop-receiving-google-chrome-updates-because-this-linux  and Google Chrome is not provided by Ubuntu repositories. "Why is it no longer supported?" You need to ask google.

Comment: if your laptop’s CPU architecture is 64bit (x86-64), you probably should install a 64bit OS. you can check your arch by running `lscpu`.

Answer (score 8):

Google Chrome is not Ubuntu.

Your 14.04 Ubuntu release and all software from the official repositories will be fully supported until April 2019.

The problem is that Google Chrome is not part of the official repositories and not maintained by Canonical or the Ubuntu community. Therefore we are not responsible for updates, but Google. And they decided to stop supporting all 32 bit versions of Chrome.

You should switch to another browser and leave Google Chrome. Alternatives are for example

- Firefox
- Chromium (an open source variant of Chrome)
- Opera
- Epiphany
- ...

There is absolutely no need to switch your operating system. You could update to 15.10 (supported until July 2016 only), or simply wait for the next LTS (Long Term Support = 5 years) release 16.04 which comes out in April 2016, if you want. This would not bring you Google Chrome support back though, as long as you stay with the 32 bit version.