# Anyone else still getting Chrome updates on 12.04 64-bit?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

I run Ubuntu 12.04 on a chromebook (ChrUbuntu) and have the Chrome browser installed.

Upon opening Chrome, I get the message that it won't receive updates, and a link to Google's page which says minimum is 14.04.**Yet Chrome keeps updating successfully**, I'm now on 49.0.2623.108.  Anyone else on 12.04 still getting updates?  What's the issue with 12.04 that concerns Google - perhaps the kernel version?

This isn't a duplicate of questions about 32-bit support.  I still wonder if Google realise there is a 64-bit version of 12.04...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Google Chrome will not be supported?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/725767/why-google-chrome-will-not-be-supported). Google ended support for Google Chrome on 32-bit Linux, Ubuntu Precise (12.04), and Debian 7. This means Precise 64bit is also not supported.

Comment: @mikewhatever - He says he IS still getting updates.

Comment: How did you install Chrome? What's the output of `apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable`?

Comment: Apologies didn't see the question. The command apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable gives:                                                                        google-chrome-stable:
  Installed: 49.0.2623.110-1
  Candidate: 49.0.2623.110-1
  Version table:
 *** 49.0.2623.110-1 0
        500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: I installed Chrome ages ago by downloading from their website and installed using Ubuntu Software Centre. Still getting updates BTW...

Answer (score 0):

Chrome or Chromium do not support Ubuntu 12.04 any more.

It is not a kernel issue. It is a dependencies issue with the DE packages.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer doesn't explain why I am happily responding on the latest version of Chrome.  However I think I found possible explanation.  It still works because I have Chromium *and* Chrome installed.  Chrome seems to depend on part of the Chromium install or settings.  When I uninstalled Chromium, Chrome required a fresh sign in every time I opened it and said my profile couldn't be opened properly.  I doubt it would work if you tried a fresh install of Chrome on 12.04, but installing Chromium as well might be worth a try.  Or of course upgrade to 14.04/16.04, I just have reasons for not wanting to do that right now.  I'll leave things as they are and will keep enjoying the updates - if they stop I'll be happy with Firefox, which is my preferred browser most of the time.