# Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: apt, package-management, 64-bit, 32-bit, multiarch

Getting below error message while issuing :

```
sudo apt-get update

Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [95.8 kB]
Ign:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease                                                                                                            
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                         
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-x/vulkan/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                
Hit:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.2 Release                                                                            
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                  
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease                                                     
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                   
Ign:9 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                                           
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                              
Get:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [782 B]      
Hit:13 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release                  
Ign:14 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-wily InRelease          
Hit:15 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-wily Release            
Get:16 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [181 B]  
Hit:17 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release                                  
Get:20 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,191 B]
Fetched 98.0 kB in 0s (118 kB/s)                                 
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

This cuts across various releases of ubuntu

Also seeing a similar glitch after enabling Ubuntu pro on my 22.04 ... now shows

```
sudo apt-get update
... 
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://esm.ubuntu.com/realtime/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Comment: @Pilot6 (and others who voted for this question being off-topic): This is not specific to a particular Ubuntu version. It affects all users of Google Chrome on Ubuntu who have the Chrome repository enabled.

Comment: Chrome repository?

Comment: @guntbert: I referred to Google's repository from where the updates are fetched.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson what's the point of re-opening, since it's a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error anyway?

Comment: @muru: Wasn't aware of that extensive answer to the other question. But then this is a duplicate, and not off-topic. OTOH, I guess it's useful to keep a question with the wording of the error message in the title, expecially since it shows up also on 64 bits installs.

Comment: I can't see, why this should be a duplicate of the mentioned question. The source of the problem is the same, but the context is different (64 vs 32 bit).

Comment: @muru: Pasting the error message into Google just brought me here, and since I've already up-voted it, it's apparently not the first time. Whatever technicalities people may bring up about the validity of this question, it's obviously useful for many people… 194 and counting, at this point.

Comment: @MichaelScheper that is irrelevant, since you would have gotten redirected to the dupe otherwise.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523447/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages

Comment: For what it's worth this applies to more than just Chrome. I had the same issue with the repository for cloudflared.

Answer (score 524, accepted):

I tracked down offending repo (any for Google chrome in this dir)

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
grep chrome * | grep -v amd64
```

or more generally

```
grep -r google  /etc/apt | grep -v amd64
```

Now do same as below for each repo file which matches above

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-unstable.list

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

SOLUTION : limit to just 64 bit by introducing the [arch=amd64]

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

similar solution to fixing bug when upgrading to Ubuntu pro

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-realtime-kernel.list  
#  original bad ... comment out next line
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/realtime/ubuntu jammy main
#  fixed by adding [arch=amd64] to above line as per
deb [arch=amd64] https://esm.ubuntu.com/realtime/ubuntu jammy main
```

NOTE : If you are trying to apply this solution for another package which as a .list file containing a line similar to this :

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-main.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflare.com/cloudflared jammy main
```

The solution is to add the architecture flag inside the square brackets, separated from the other arguments with a space. Here is an example :

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-main.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflare.com/cloudflared jammy main
```

---

*ROOT CAUSE* : Google dropped support for 32-bit Chrome on Linux triggering an error when updating apt in 64-bit systems (with multi arch enabled) ...  details here : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu

To confirm you are using 64 bit ubuntu with multiarch enabled issue

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

if it says

```
i386
```

then you have added 32 bit support, this will list your native arch ... issue

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

if you are native 64 you will see this output so do SOLUTION shown above

```
amd64
```

issue below to show packages using 32 bit

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep 386
```

Here is the command to remove multi architecture ( only if you have no 32 bit applications )

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

Comment: This answer works very well (thank you!), however the file that needs to be edited (in your example /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-unstable.list) is automatically configured on a regular basis, so the fix is written over and needs to be added over and over again. Any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: How to list `i386` architectures?

Comment: I love the thoroughness of this answer. Good work. Thank you.

Comment: @EugenKonkov dpkg --get-selections | grep 386 might help

Comment: Cloudflared [https://pkg.cloudflare.com/index.html] introduces this issue on Ubuntu 22.04; love how well this was documented; thank you

Comment: I came here because I got the same error after installing brave-browser.  Your solution worked.

Comment: This answer helped me fix what turned out to be the same issue for the Keybase package. I just made the same change in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/keybase.list`, adding `[arch=amd64]` and that fixed the issue. _(I also applied the more permanent fix in Eric Mintz' solution - see my comment there.)_

Comment: Still not working for me, great instructions, but ....

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d ❯❯❯ sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
Alias tip: _ dpkg --remove-architecture i386
dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'i386' currently in use by the database
`

Comment: I was getting this error w/ a different apt repo. This answer is particularly helpful because I wanted to know _why_ it happens as well as how to fix it. Now I know it's because of multi architecture, how to verify that, AND how to fix it.

Answer (score 43):

(this solution is for Ubuntu Bionic Beaver)
First, shame on Google for letting this issue linger so long!!

Here's how to fix it:
As already mentioned above, editing files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` seems to work... but only temporarily. The next day, the problem is back.

Here's why:

The file `/etc/cron.daily/google-earth-pro` runs daily and overwrites what you have in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth-pro.list`.

To fix it once and for all, edit `/etc/cron.daily/google-earth-pro`.
Find this line:

```
REPOCONFIG="deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main"
```

...and change it to:

```
REPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main"
```

Comment: For immediate change for Google Earth, it might be worth editing the files `google-earth-pro.list` and `google-earth-pro.list.save`.

Comment: The line to change would be at LINE 24

Comment: Thank you. `[arch=amd64]` solved my problem with virtualbox 6.0

Comment: Interesting, I did this AND the sources file still gets re-written.

Comment: @AndorKiss Yes, that's what this cron job is doing. That's why this answer is here.

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` covers `google-chrome-stable`, `google-chrome-beta` and `google-chrome-unstable`. `cat /opt/google/chrome-beta/cron/google-chrome-beta | grep "REPOCONFIG="`. `cat /opt/google/chrome-unstable/cron/google-chrome-unstable | grep "REPOCONFIG="`. All three point to `stable`.

Comment: This answer helped me fix what turned out to be the same issue for the Keybase package. I edited `/etc/cron.daily/keybase` and edited the lines that include `REPOCONFIG` and `SSLREPOCONFIG` to include `[arch=amd64]`. _(Based on comments in that file, it looks like the Keybase team copied the Google Chrome package file that had this same issue and modified it.)_

Answer (score 27):

Changing

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

to

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

in each of

- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-musicmanager.list`
- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-musicmanager.list.save`
- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-musicmanager.list.distUpgrade`

seems to fix the issue for Google Music Manager for Play Music too. Not sure if it will revert these changes at some point as the files are automatically configured.

Comment: for me file to change was `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list`

Comment: ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.

Answer (score 7):

Although Google has fixed this issue for *Chrome*, it still appears for e.g.  *Google Earth*.

Adding `[arch=amd64]` fixes the issue, but it needs to be added over and over again.

After making the file immutable as proposed by a [webupd8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html) and running into [issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031553/permission-denied-etc-apt-sources-list-d-google-earth-list) because of that, my current solution is to add a cronjob to apply the fix automatically once every hour:

```
~$ sudo crontab -e

0 * * * * sed -i 's/^deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list
```

(Replace `google-earth.list` if necessary).

Comment: Out of curiosity what keeps changing this file? In my experience, apt sources files don't get changed by themselves

Comment: [Sergio Rus](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html#comment-2561557082) reckons that Google eventually fixed it for Chrome such that your one-time change would be preserved over updates.

Answer (score 7):

Note that the above answers give accurate solutions for the `ONE-LINE-STYLE` format `.list` files; however, the verbose `DEB822-STYLE FORMAT` needs to use the full `Architectures` option instead of the abbreviated `arch` option to restrict the repo's packages to your desired architecture.

For example:

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apache-arrow.sources


Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/arrow/ubuntu/
Suites: focal
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/apache-arrow-apt-source.gpg
Architectures: amd64
```

Details on this option and others can be found with `man sources.list`

Answer (score 4):

Though this question has been marked solved, I was unable to solve this issue with any of the above answers. I used an another method. Go to 'software & updates' > ubuntu software > download from > select best server. Now wait for some time for the system to find it out. Once this gets done, try your command again. This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well! Nice!

Comment: Glad to know :)

Answer (score 4):

I add my 2 cent. Sorry If I have a Debian 10 and not an Ubuntu, but my answer is in-topic.

I had the same problem due to mariadb repo. It was added to `sources.list` as

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://ftp.nluug.nl/db/mariadb/repo/10.3/debian buster main
```

I simply removed `i386` and `ppc64el`

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://ftp.nluug.nl/db/mariadb/repo/10.3/debian buster main
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if this question is marked solved, for me, on Ubuntu 18.04, changed a line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` from    `deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`
to `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`.

There was no file named `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-unstable.list`.
Making the same changes in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` gave warnings saying that target package is configured multiple times. (in `sources.list` and `google-chrome.list`)

Answer (score 2):

Change my source list

```
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main
```

to

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main
```