# Repository failure with google chrome

Tags: apt, google-chrome, repository, google

```
Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

is what i get when performing

```
sudo apt-get update.
```

I found a solution on this website ([Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x))

and performed

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

but got back

```
No command 'deb' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dex' from package 'dex' (universe)
 Command 'debc' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'deb3' from package 'quilt' (main)
 Command 'dab' from package 'bsdgames' (universe)
 Command 'derb' from package 'icu-devtools' (main)
 Command 'debi' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'xdeb' from package 'xdeb' (universe)
 Command 'dwb' from package 'dwb' (universe)
deb: command not found
```

I am unable to comment on the old post because i don't have 50 reputation so i apologize for a repeat question.

Comment: Are you using a 32bit or 64bit OS?

Answer (score 23):

It's not a terminal command; it's about the contents of this file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

If you have a 64 bit installation, you should edit the file and change the last line to:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

If you have a 32 bit installation, you'd better just delete the file. There won't be any further updates of Google Chrome for 32 bit.

Comment: If you have 32-bit installation it is better to remove the repository by `sudo ppa-purge -s dl.google.com ppa:linux/chrome`. That way packages installed from the repository will be removed (or downgraded).

Answer (score 5):

This command will do!

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"
```

---

Or check on the files `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and change the line below:

> <strike>deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable
>   main</strike>
>
> deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

---

Finally..

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have Google Earth installed, please do the same.
Remove deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

Add deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

Answer (score -3):

There is a simpler solution than that one you found.

Go to "Software & Updates" => "Other Programs" and unmark `dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable`.

This will fix your problem
This will disable the update of Google Chrome too, but is the better way while I other solution doesn't appear.

Comment: I find it hard to understand how that can be "the better way" if you have a 64 bit installation, for which future Google Chrome updates will be issued.