# N: Skipping acquire of configured file... as repository... doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'

Tags: apt, updates

I am a new user in Ubuntu and installed 16.04 LTS 64-bit. I am seeing an error when I try to update

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
```

17 times the same line repeats

I have checked and read other related questions, but they are talking about a Google Chrome issue, but I don't have it in my system, All I have is Skype installed (that even doesn't run, it just appears as an icon in dash for some time),

From another [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x) I have tried

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
foreign-architecture
```

as you see it doesn't show me `amd64`.

Comment: `foreign-architecture` is not an architecture. Remove it.

Comment: it works, thanks( removed the foreign-architecture )

Comment: it also solved my skype issue, now the skype also runs, +1

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't show `amd64` is because that's not a foreign architecture, so when you ask for foreign architectures, it will naturally not be listed. `dpkg --print-architecture` will report `amd64`.

To remove the erroneous architecture, run:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture foreign-architecture
```