Brave Nightly package skipping acquire because computer isn't i386
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

How can I fix this error for sudo apt update?

The answer is in https://askubuntu.com/questions/964100/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-xxxx-as-repository-xxxx-xenial-inrelease which I closed this post as a duplicate of.  See the answers there which indicate adding something to your sources.list.d entries for Brave's repos

Similarly to the other question, but for the nightly version, configuring the sources.list.d entry:
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-nightly-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com/ stable main"|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-nightly.list
