# How to install the Wire messenger desktop app/client on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, client, open-source, instant-messaging

The secure and private Wire messenger app with [end-to-end encryption](https://wire.com/en/privacy/) is a great open source alternative for Whatsapp, Skype, Viber, WeChat, FB Messenger, Telegram. You don't need a cell phone number to login. These feature were attracting me and I can use it on [almost all platforms](https://wire.com/en/download/) (Linux. Android. iOS. Mac. Windows.) inclusive within the most common browsers.

There is also a standalone desktop version/client. How do I install the wire desktop client in Ubuntu?

Comment: An alternative to Skype too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Wire](https://wire.com/) is getting more popular, there are [more possibilities](https://wire.com/en/download/) by now and as the updates are usually done within the Desktop app, it probably does not matter much which one you choose:

1. [Install via **Debian repository**](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-desktop/wiki/How-to-install-Wire-for-Desktop-on-Linux), instructions see below.
2. [**Snap** package](https://snapcraft.io/wire) from the Ubuntu Software Center (`gnome-software`) or type in a terminal: `sudo snap install wire`. *Thank you [mook765](https://askubuntu.com/users/590937/mook765) for the [hint](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141099/30631), please vote his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141099/30631) up, too.*

*Install it directly from the [Wire homepage](https://wire.com/en/download/). Click on `Details` below the Linux option/penguin and choose Deb package (Ubuntu 64Bit) or AppImage:*
3. [**Deb package**](https://wire-app.wire.com/linux/debian/pool/main/Wire-3.9.2895_amd64.deb) (64bit).
4. [**AppImage**](https://wire-app.wire.com/linux/Wire-3.9.2895_x86_64.AppImage) (64bit).
5. You can also get the [**source code directly**](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-desktop).

Wire for Linux is still a **beta** so you should expect bugs and crashes. Be sure to **file feedback and point out problems on** [the Wire GitHub page](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-desktop/issues).

**To install via Debian repository (works on Ubuntu):**
To add the [**Wire repository** and PGP key run these commands](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-desktop/wiki/How-to-install-Wire-for-Desktop-on-Linux) in a new Terminal window.

1. First install apt-transport-https to fetch packages over HTTPS

   ```
   sudo apt install apt-transport-https
   ```
2. Import the Wire PGP signing key to verify installed packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://wire-app.wire.com/linux/releases.key
   ```
3. Add the Wire repo to your Software Sources list

   ```
   echo "deb https://wire-app.wire.com/linux/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wire-desktop.list
   ```
4. Finally, update Ubuntu’s list of available packages and install Wire for Linux on Ubuntu with this command combo:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install wire-desktop
   ```

If you get the **error** `N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://wire-app.wire.com/linux/debian stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386`, follow [this answer's advise](https://askubuntu.com/a/741411/30631). In a terminal:

- Open the source list of Wire Desktop to edit it in gedit:

  sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wire-desktop.list
- Add `[arch=amd64]`to the one line so it looks like this:
  `deb [arch=amd64] https://wire-app.wire.com/linux/debian stable main`

[Ferdi](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141099/30631), messaging browser that allows you to combine your favourite messaging services into one application - free & open-Source alternative to Franz & Rambox.
[You can install it as deb, AppImage or Snap package.](https://wire-app.wire.com/linux/debian/pool/main/Wire-3.9.2895_amd64.deb)

Source: [Wire APT announcement](https://medium.com/@wireapp/a-step-forward-for-wire-for-linux-52f0538cac15), [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/wire-linux-apt-repo).

Comment: Is there any step by step guide to install wire server on ubuntu 18?

Comment: @Umair I have not found anything, just some general instructions, you have probably seen as well: [Wire Server Deploy](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-server-deploy), [Wire Server readme](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-server/blob/develop/README.md#1-compile-sources-natively), [How to run wire-server with "fake" AWS dependencies in demo mode](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-server/blob/develop/deploy/services-demo/README.md). If you succeed to do it, please open a new question and provide the step-by-step guide as an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wire is also available as a snap and can be easily installed with

```
sudo snap install wire
```

or alternatively, install it using `gnome-software`, which will provide a simple way to configure the snaps permissions after installation.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Rambox](http://rambox.pro/), an Electron based

> Free, Open Source and Cross Platform messaging and emailing app that combines common web applications into one.

*Wire* is among the [available services](https://github.com/saenzramiro/rambox#services-available---95) along with WhatsApp, Messenger, Viber, Telegram, Google Hangouts, Gmail, Twitter etc. There is also an option to add services manually.

To install Rambox, first download the `deb` package right for your system from their [official GitHub page](https://github.com/saenzramiro/rambox/releases), for example [64 bit package](https://github.com/saenzramiro/rambox/releases/download/0.5.13/Rambox_0.5.13-x64.deb)  or [32 bit package](https://github.com/saenzramiro/rambox/releases/download/0.5.13/Rambox_0.5.13-ia32.deb) of the latest release (v0.5.13). Then run the following command in Terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/the/package/package-name.deb
```

For example if you have downloaded the 64 bit package linked above to your Downloads folder then run

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/Rambox_0.5.13-x64.deb
```