# How to autostart the Wire desktop client minimized?

Tags: .desktop, autostart, system-tray, instant-messaging

I sucessfully installed the [Wire messenger desktop client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964757/how-to-install-the-wire-messenger-desktop-app-client-on-ubuntu). How can I start it minimized every time I log in to my account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More recent versions of the Wire desktop client have an option to launch it on startup:

[image]

---

If that did not work as expected:

For a minimized application icon of the messenger Wire we need to have a system tray extension installed. This will be provided with the [ubuntu-unity-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040890/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-desktop-use-unity-be-like-ubuntu-14-04), or if running default Ubuntu >= 18.04 with the package [gnome-shell-extension-top-icons-plus](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnome-shell-extension-top-icons-plus).

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-top-icons-plus
```

If Wire was installed by [DEB package or from the Debian repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964757/how-to-install-the-wire-messenger-desktop-app-client-on-ubuntu) a `wire-desktop.desktop` file can be put in the [autostart directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) to start every time we log into our session with the following content (copied from `/usr/share/applications`):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Wire
Exec=/opt/Wire/wire-desktop %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=wire-desktop
StartupWMClass=Wire
Categories=Network;
GenericName=Wire
Keywords=chat;encrypt;e2e;messenger;videocall
```

If that worked as expected we can have it starting minimized to the tray with the [parameter](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-desktop/wiki/Start-Parameters) `--startup` in the Exec line of our `.desktop` file:

```
Exec=/opt/Wire/wire-desktop --startup %U
```

After login we will have Wire running minimized as icon in the system tray:

[image]