# Is there a way to use Threema on a Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: software-recommendation, skype, open-source, instant-messaging

The [secure and private Threema messenger](https://threema.ch/) app (based in Switzerland) with end-to-end encryption is a great [open source alternative](https://github.com/threema-ch) for WhatsApp, Skype, Viber, WeChat, FB Messenger, Telegram.
Is there a way to use Threema on a Ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [**Threema 2.0** for desktop, Beta version](https://threema.ch/en/faq/md_overview), only with **iOS** Threema app as flatpak, from [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/ch.threema.threema-web-desktop) or command line [[Flatpak setup needed first]](https://www.flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu):

   flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
   flatpak install --from https://releases.threema.ch/flatpak/threema-desktop/ch.threema.threema-desktop.flatpakref
2. [**Threema for Desktop**](https://threema.ch/en/blog/posts/threema-for-desktop) (an Electron-App), as a [deb-package](https://threema.ch/en/download#desktop). Outlook: Threema 2.0 for Desktop [is worked on, with the multi-device technology.](https://threema.ch/en/blog/posts/threema-for-desktop)

- Helpful tool: [Session password](https://threema.ch/en/faq/web_session)
  Enter a session password in the desktop app or the web client before scanning the displayed QR code with your mobile device. To use the desktop app or the web client the next time on the same computer, you can simply enter this password (instead of scanning the QR code again).
  This way, it’s also **possible to use Threema if your mobile device isn’t present** (provided it’s connected to the Internet).
  But hopefully [Threema 2.0 for Desktop will come soon](https://threema.ch/en/blog/posts/threema-for-desktop)!

3. **Threema Web** ([web.threema.ch](https://web.threema.ch)) is Threema’s web client. It allows you to use Threema on the desktop without compromising security.
   By *scanning a QR code*, desktop and mobile device are connected at once, and all conversations are fully accessible on the desktop.
   More details on the [Threema webpage](https://threema.ch/en/faq/web_info).
4. [**openMittsu**](https://www.openmittsu.de) is a cross-platform open source implementation and desktop **standalone** client for the Threema Messenger App. More infos on the [openMittsu Github page](https://github.com/blizzard4591/openMittsu).
   You can use the [repository](https://downloads.openmittsu.de/deb/), or install the packages directly.
   If you like to use the repository, add the GPG key for the repository:

```
wget -O- https://packages.openmittsu.de/openmittsu.packages.gpg.key|apt-key add -
```

Now, add the repository. As root or using sudo, create a file called `openmittsu.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` with the following contents:

```
deb https://packages.openmittsu.de/apt/debian stretch main
```

You can now install (or update) openMittsu using:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install openmittsu
```

5. [**Ferdium**](https://github.com/ferdium) (Fork of Ferdi, a fork of Franz), messaging browser that allows you to combine your favourite messaging services into one application - free & open-Source alternative to Rambox.
   [You can install it as deb.](https://ferdium.org/download)
6. [**Rambox**](https://rambox.pro), an Electron based Free, Open Source and Cross Platform messaging and emailing app that combines common web applications into one.

   *Threema* is among the [available services](https://rambox.app/#apps) along with [Wire](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964757/how-to-install-the-wire-messenger-desktop-app-client-on-ubuntu) etc. There is also an option to add services manually.

   To install Rambox, first download the `deb` package right for your system from their [official GitHub page](https://github.com/ramboxapp/community-edition/releases). Then run the following command in Terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/the/package/package-name.deb
```