# Failed to fetch Google Earth 32-bit

Tags: updates, software-sources, google-earth

Running `sudo apt update`, I got this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

How do I fix this? I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

**Update**: I followed [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001225/301745), but the error returned today. The file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list` is back to the way it was, and I just noticed it has these two lines:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
```

So it seems the file was overwritten, meaning the current answer is not a permanent fix, and neither is the duplicate.

**Update 2**: I've decided to uninstall Google Earth and delete its .list file. I never use it anyway. If anyone is having the same issue, let me know and I'll help you out.

**Update 3**: muru mentioned in the comments that there is a cron file, `/etc/cron.daily/google-earth`. I read through it and found it appends this to the .list file:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
```

So maybe editing this part of the cron job, or disabling it outright, would solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/cron.daily/google-earth` file?

Comment: @muru Yes, and it has this line which gets appended to the .list file: `REPOCONFIG="deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/q/741410/301745) - different error, but similar issue

Comment: I found that editing the cron script seems to do the trick. Very easy to demonstrate: simply execute that script, and then observe the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list`. Thanks for discovering/pointing out that this cron script existed - I didn't even consider that this is how the file (`google-earth.list`) was getting overwritten.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer on this similar question: [No more updates for Google Chrome 32-bit](https://askubuntu.com/q/724093/301745)

I ran `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list`, and changed this line:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
```

to this:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
```

Then `sudo apt update` succeeded.

Comment: Note that in my latest version it is Google Earth Pro so when I have problems I run  sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth-pro.list"

Comment: @Dennis Take a look at edit 3 in my question. You probably have a cron job at `/etc/cron.daily/google-earth-pro` that you could edit.

Comment: Good point. I was mainly commenting on the fact that the name changed and didn't think so much about the answer itself.  I wonder though are there benefits to the cron job that might be missed by doing so?  I don't understand it all but it looks like a lot of error checking and fixing.

Comment: @Dennis Right, the name is different. About the cron job, I meant to say you could edit it instead of disabling it. I just clarified that bit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing this part of the question:

> So it seems the file was overwritten, meaning the current answer is
>   not a permanent fix, and neither is the duplicate.

I have this problem with both google 'earth' and 'chrome' (of the corrected source lists getting overwritten). To solve it, I made a copy of the correct source lists and saved them off, then I made a script `fix-google` that copies the saved versions over the ones in `/etc/apt`. Since I always do updates with `aptitude`, I changed the script I use to start `aptitude` to run `fix-google` before it starts `aptitude`. Kludgy but it works. I found this problem super annoying