# problem installing Epson Iscan for V370 scanner in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, scanner

When installing the Epson Iscan driver for a V370 scanner 64 bit the following message appears and the installation fails 
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x)

Answer (score 0):

In `terminal`...

`cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d` # change directory

`grep -i earth *.list` # note the name of the found file

`sudo pico google-earth-pro.list` # edit the file using the above found filename

change:

`deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main`

to:

`deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main`

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> # to save edits

<kbd>return</kbd> # to confirm the filename to save

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> # to exit the editor

**Update #1:**

To solve the **new** errors that you detailed...

In `terminal`...

```
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth-pro.list.save.1

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

then run `Y PPA Manager` and click the `Advanced` icon, and select `Try to import all missing GPG keys` and `Try to fix all GPG BADSIG errors`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  however when I enter the first command line I get the following error message.bash: cd: /etc/apt/sources.list: Not a directory

Comment: @Trevor  Oops... silly me... small typo, now corrected. Also, there's no ":" after cd.

Comment: @Trevor  If my answer proves helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the grey checkmark icon. Thanks.

Comment: I have successfully changed  the name. However when run ./install I get the following errors.
N: Ignoring file 'google-earth-pro.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

Comment: @Trevor oh... you didn't identify those errors in your question. Please edit your original question with this new information. Also, start comments to me with `@heynnema` or I'll miss them. See the update to my answer. Report back.