# Install .deb Package Error (dpkg error)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I downloaded the .deb extension package to my Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS machine. I use the *dpkg* command to install this package, but I get the error like this:

```
hie@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg -i mender-client_2.1.0-1_armhf.deb
Selecting previously unselected package mender-client:armhf.
Selecting previously unselected package mender-client:armhf.
(Reading database ... 197100 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mender-client_2.1.0-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking mender-client:armhf (2.1.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mender-client:armhf:
 mender-client:armhf depends on libc6 (>= 2.12).
 mender-client:armhf depends on liblzma5 (>= 5.1).

dpkg: error processing package mender-client:armhf (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mender-client:armhf
```

That's my error and I've tried a lot to fix this error, but I haven't succeeded.
When I enter *sudo apt-get update*, I get an output like this:

```
hie@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/longsleep/golang-backports/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [748 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [595 kB]
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main armhf Packages
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [291 kB]
Ign:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted armhf Packages
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [458 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [396 kB]
Ign:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe armhf Packages
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [187 kB]
Ign:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main armhf Packages
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main armhf Packages
Ign:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe armhf Packages
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main armhf Packages
Ign:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,033 kB]
Err:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Ign:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe armhf Packages
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [860 kB]
Ign:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main armhf Packages
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [402 kB]
Ign:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [764 kB]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [695 kB]
Ign:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe armhf Packages
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [320 kB]
Ign:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main armhf Packages
Ign:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe armhf Packages
Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main armhf Packages
Ign:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted armhf Packages
Ignite http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe armhf Packages
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main armhf Packages
Ign:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe armhf Packages
Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main armhf Packages
Ign:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe armhf Packages
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main armhf Packages
Ign:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe armhf Packages
Err:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Ign:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe armhf Packages
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse armhf Packages
Err:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Ign:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Err:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Ign:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe armhf Packages
Fetched 325 kB in 14s (22.2 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/longsleep/golang-backports/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-arm/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I may also have changed something in /etc/apt/source.list file. I don't know if this is the problem, but I would like to share the source.list with you in case it helps.

```
hie@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
```

Comment: I see many different errors; I suggest remove the sources that don't support your arm architecture, as for the primary issue I'd `apt-cache policy libc6` as 16.04 does have it (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libc6), do you have it installed?  (`dpkg` requires all requirements to be pre-installed, where as `apt` does not - have you tried `apt` to install if not pre-installed?)

Comment: @karel If something there *really* solves this specific dependency problem (note also the difference in architectures, with this being an armhf system on which multiple dpkg architectures are probably not even enabled), then I think that should be explained before closing this, or perhaps even this should have an answer that explains it in this context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/q/741410/)