# Upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10, then to 20.04, I have a few i386 packages that can't be upgraded, can I purge them?

Tags: 32-bit, 20.04

When performing `$ sudo dpkg -l | grep i386` I get the following list :

```
gcc-10-base:i386                    i386   GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
glib-networking:i386                i386   network-related giomodules for GLib
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386      i386   GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386      i386   GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
gstreamer1.0-x:i386                 i386   GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
i965-va-driver:i386                 i386   VAAPI driver for Intel G45 & HD Graphics family
intel-media-va-driver:i386          i386   VAAPI driver for the Intel GEN8+ Graphics family
libaa1:i386                         i386   ASCII art library
libaom0:i386                        i386   AV1 Video Codec Library
libasn1-8-heimdal:i386              i386   Heimdal Kerberos - ASN.1 library
libasound2:i386                     i386   shared library for ALSA applications
libasound2-plugins:i386             i386   ALSA library additional plugins
libasyncns0:i386                    i386   Asynchronous name service query library
libatomic1:i386                     i386   support library providing __atomic built-in functions
libavahi-client3:i386               i386   Avahi client library
libavahi-common-data:i386           i386   Avahi common data files
libavahi-common3:i386               i386   Avahi common library
libavc1394-0:i386                   i386   control IEEE 1394 audio/video devices
libavcodec58:i386                   i386   FFmpeg library with de/encoders for audio/video codecs - runtime files
libavutil56:i386                    i386   FFmpeg library with functions for simplifying programming - runtime files
libblkid1:i386                      i386   block device ID library
libbrotli1:i386                     i386   library implementing brotli encoder and decoder (shared libraries)
libbsd0:i386                        i386   utility functions from BSD systems - shared library
libbz2-1.0:i386                     i386   high-quality block-sorting file compressor library - runtime
libc6:i386                          i386   GNU C Library: Shared libraries
libcaca0:i386                       i386   colour ASCII art library
libcairo-gobject2:i386              i386   Cairo 2D vector graphics library (GObject library)
libcairo2:i386                      i386   Cairo 2D vector graphics library
libcap2:i386                        i386   POSIX 1003.1e capabilities (library)
libcapi20-3:i386                    i386   ISDN utilities - CAPI support libraries
libcdparanoia0:i386                 i386   audio extraction tool for sampling CDs (library)
libcodec2-0.9:i386                  i386   Codec2 runtime library
libcom-err2:i386                    i386   common error description library
libcrypt1:i386                      i386   libcrypt shared library
libcups2:i386                       i386   Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Core library
libcurl3-gnutls:i386                i386   easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
libdatrie1:i386                     i386   Double-array trie library
libdb5.3:i386                       i386   Berkeley v5.3 Database Libraries [runtime]
libdbus-1-3:i386                    i386   simple interprocess messaging system (library)
libdrm-amdgpu1:i386                 i386   Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
libdrm-intel1:i386                  i386   Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
libdrm-nouveau2:i386                i386   Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
libdrm-radeon1:i386                 i386   Userspace interface to radeon-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
libdrm2:i386                        i386   Userspace interface to kernel DRM services -- runtime
libdv4:i386                         i386   software library for DV format digital video (runtime lib)
libedit2:i386                       i386   BSD editline and history libraries
libelf1:i386                        i386   library to read and write ELF files
libexif12:i386                      i386   library to parse EXIF files
libexpat1:i386                      i386   XML parsing C library - runtime library
libfaudio0:i386                     i386   XAudio sound processing reimplementation - library
libffi7:i386                        i386   Foreign Function Interface library runtime
libflac8:i386                       i386   Free Lossless Audio Codec - runtime C library
libfontconfig1:i386                 i386   generic font configuration library - runtime
libfreetype6:i386                   i386   FreeType 2 font engine, shared library files
libfribidi0:i386                    i386   Free Implementation of the Unicode BiDi algorithm
libgcc-s1:i386                      i386   GCC support library
libgcrypt20:i386                    i386   LGPL Crypto library - runtime library
libgd3:i386                         i386   GD Graphics Library
libgdbm-compat4:i386                i386   GNU dbm database routines (legacy support runtime version) 
libgdbm6:i386                       i386   GNU dbm database routines (runtime version) 
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386             i386   GDK Pixbuf library
libgl1:i386                         i386   Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- legacy GL support
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                i386   free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
libglapi-mesa:i386                  i386   free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
libglib2.0-0:i386                   i386   GLib library of C routines
libglu1-mesa:i386                   i386   Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
libglvnd0:i386                      i386   Vendor neutral GL dispatch library
libglx-mesa0:i386                   i386   free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
libglx0:i386                        i386   Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GLX support
libgmp10:i386                       i386   Multiprecision arithmetic library
libgnutls30:i386                    i386   GNU TLS library - main runtime library
libgomp1:i386                       i386   GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library
libgpg-error0:i386                  i386   GnuPG development runtime library
libgphoto2-6:i386                   i386   gphoto2 digital camera library
libgphoto2-port12:i386              i386   gphoto2 digital camera port library
libgpm2:i386                        i386   General Purpose Mouse - shared library
libgraphite2-3:i386                 i386   Font rendering engine for Complex Scripts -- library
libgsm1:i386                        i386   Shared libraries for GSM speech compressor
libgssapi-krb5-2:i386               i386   MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - krb5 GSS-API Mechanism
libgssapi3-heimdal:i386             i386   Heimdal Kerberos - GSSAPI support library
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 i386   GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 i386   GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
libgstreamer1.0-0:i386              i386   Core GStreamer libraries and elements
libgudev-1.0-0:i386                 i386   GObject-based wrapper library for libudev
libharfbuzz0b:i386                  i386   OpenType text shaping engine (shared library)
libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386            i386   Heimdal Kerberos - crypto library
libheimbase1-heimdal:i386           i386   Heimdal Kerberos - Base library
libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386           i386   Heimdal Kerberos - NTLM support library
libhogweed5:i386                    i386   low level cryptographic library (public-key cryptos)
libhx509-5-heimdal:i386             i386   Heimdal Kerberos - X509 support library
libicu66:i386                       i386   International Components for Unicode
libidn2-0:i386                      i386   Internationalized domain names (IDNA2008/TR46) library
libiec61883-0:i386                  i386   partial implementation of IEC 61883 (shared lib)
libieee1284-3:i386                  i386   cross-platform library for parallel port access
libigdgmm11:i386                    i386   Intel Graphics Memory Management Library -- shared library
libjack-jackd2-0:i386               i386   JACK Audio Connection Kit (libraries)
libjbig0:i386                       i386   JBIGkit libraries
libjpeg-turbo8:i386                 i386   IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
libjpeg8:i386                       i386   Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
libk5crypto3:i386                   i386   MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Crypto Library
libkeyutils1:i386                   i386   Linux Key Management Utilities (library)
libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386             i386   Heimdal Kerberos - libraries
libkrb5-3:i386                      i386   MIT Kerberos runtime libraries
libkrb5support0:i386                i386   MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Support library
liblcms2-2:i386                     i386   Little CMS 2 color management library
libldap-2.4-2:i386                  i386   OpenLDAP libraries
libllvm9:i386                       i386   Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library
libltdl7:i386                       i386   System independent dlopen wrapper for GNU libtool
liblz4-1:i386                       i386   Fast LZ compression algorithm library - runtime
liblzma5:i386                       i386   XZ-format compression library
libmount1:i386                      i386   device mounting library
libmp3lame0:i386                    i386   MP3 encoding library
libmpg123-0:i386                    i386   MPEG layer 1/2/3 audio decoder (shared library)
libmysqlclient21:i386               i386   MySQL database client library
libncurses6:i386                    i386   shared libraries for terminal handling
libncursesw6:i386                   i386   shared libraries for terminal handling (wide character support)
libnettle7:i386                     i386   low level cryptographic library (symmetric and one-way cryptos)
libnghttp2-14:i386                  i386   library implementing HTTP/2 protocol (shared library)
libnuma1:i386                       i386   Libraries for controlling NUMA policy
libnvidia-compute-440:i386          i386   NVIDIA libcompute package
libnvidia-decode-440:i386           i386   NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
libnvidia-encode-440:i386           i386   NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386             i386   NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
libnvidia-gl-440:i386               i386   NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386             i386   NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
libodbc1:i386                       i386   ODBC library for Unix
libogg0:i386                        i386   Ogg bitstream library
libopenal1:i386                     i386   Software implementation of the OpenAL audio API (shared library)
libopenjp2-7:i386                   i386   JPEG 2000 image compression/decompression library
libopus0:i386                       i386   Opus codec runtime library
liborc-0.4-0:i386                   i386   Library of Optimized Inner Loops Runtime Compiler
libosmesa6:i386                     i386   Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
libp11-kit0:i386                    i386   library for loading and coordinating access to PKCS#11 modules - runtime
libpango-1.0-0:i386                 i386   Layout and rendering of internationalized text
libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386            i386   Layout and rendering of internationalized text
libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386              i386   Layout and rendering of internationalized text
libpcap0.8:i386                     i386   system interface for user-level packet capture
libpci3:i386                        i386   PCI utilities (shared library)
libpciaccess0:i386                  i386   Generic PCI access library for X
libpcre2-8-0:i386                   i386   New Perl Compatible Regular Expression Library- 8 bit runtime files
libpcre3:i386                       i386   Old Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - runtime files
libperl5.30:i386                    i386   shared Perl library
libpixman-1-0:i386                  i386   pixel-manipulation library for X and cairo
libpng16-16:i386                    i386   PNG library - runtime (version 1.6)
libproxy1v5:i386                    i386   automatic proxy configuration management library (shared)
libpsl5:i386                        i386   Library for Public Suffix List (shared libraries)
libpulse0:i386                      i386   PulseAudio client libraries
libraw1394-11:i386                  i386   library for direct access to IEEE 1394 bus (aka FireWire)
libroken18-heimdal:i386             i386   Heimdal Kerberos - roken support library
librsvg2-2:i386                     i386   SAX-based renderer library for SVG files (runtime)
librsvg2-common:i386                i386   SAX-based renderer library for SVG files (extra runtime)
librtmp1:i386                       i386   toolkit for RTMP streams (shared library)
libsamplerate0:i386                 i386   Audio sample rate conversion library
libsane:i386                        i386   API library for scanners
libsasl2-2:i386                     i386   Cyrus SASL - authentication abstraction library
libsasl2-modules:i386               i386   Cyrus SASL - pluggable authentication modules
libsasl2-modules-db:i386            i386   Cyrus SASL - pluggable authentication modules (DB)
libsdl2-2.0-0:i386                  i386   Simple DirectMedia Layer
libselinux1:i386                    i386   SELinux runtime shared libraries
libsensors5:i386                    i386   library to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
libshine3:i386                      i386   Fixed-point MP3 encoding library - runtime files
libshout3:i386                      i386   MP3/Ogg Vorbis broadcast streaming library
libslang2:i386                      i386   S-Lang programming library - runtime version
libsnappy1v5:i386                   i386   fast compression/decompression library
libsndfile1:i386                    i386   Library for reading/writing audio files
libsndio7.0:i386                    i386   Small audio and MIDI framework from OpenBSD, runtime libraries
libsnmp35:i386                      i386   SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library
libsoup2.4-1:i386                   i386   HTTP library implementation in C -- Shared library
libsoxr0:i386                       i386   High quality 1D sample-rate conversion library
libspeex1:i386                      i386   The Speex codec runtime library
libsqlite3-0:i386                   i386   SQLite 3 shared library
libssh-4:i386                       i386   tiny C SSH library (OpenSSL flavor)
libssl1.1:i386                      i386   Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
libstb0:i386                        i386   single-file public domain (or MIT licensed) libraries for C/C++
libstdc++6:i386                     i386   GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libswresample3:i386                 i386   FFmpeg library for audio resampling, rematrixing etc. - runtime files
libsystemd0:i386                    i386   systemd utility library
libtag1v5:i386                      i386   audio meta-data library
libtag1v5-vanilla:i386              i386   audio meta-data library - vanilla flavour
libtasn1-6:i386                     i386   Manage ASN.1 structures (runtime)
libthai0:i386                       i386   Thai language support library
libtheora0:i386                     i386   Theora Video Compression Codec
libtiff5:i386                       i386   Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library
libtinfo6:i386                      i386   shared low-level terminfo library for terminal handling
libtwolame0:i386                    i386   MPEG Audio Layer 2 encoding library
libudev1:i386                       i386   libudev shared library
libunistring2:i386                  i386   Unicode string library for C
libusb-1.0-0:i386                   i386   userspace USB programming library
libuuid1:i386                       i386   Universally Unique ID library
libv4l-0:i386                       i386   Collection of video4linux support libraries
libv4lconvert0:i386                 i386   Video4linux frame format conversion library
libva-drm2:i386                     i386   Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- DRM runtime
libva-x11-2:i386                    i386   Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- X11 runtime
libva2:i386                         i386   Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- runtime
libvdpau1:i386                      i386   Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix (libraries)
libvisual-0.4-0:i386                i386   audio visualization framework
libvkd3d1:i386                      i386   Direct3D 12 to Vulkan translation - library
libvorbis0a:i386                    i386   decoder library for Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec
libvorbisenc2:i386                  i386   encoder library for Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec
libvpx6:i386                        i386   VP8 and VP9 video codec (shared library)
libvulkan1:i386                     i386   Vulkan loader library
libwavpack1:i386                    i386   audio codec (lossy and lossless) - library
libwayland-client0:i386             i386   wayland compositor infrastructure - client library
libwayland-cursor0:i386             i386   wayland compositor infrastructure - cursor library
libwayland-egl1:i386                i386   wayland compositor infrastructure - EGL library
libwebp6:i386                       i386   Lossy compression of digital photographic images.
libwebpmux3:i386                    i386   Lossy compression of digital photographic images.
libwind0-heimdal:i386               i386   Heimdal Kerberos - stringprep implementation
libwine:i386                        i386   Windows API implementation - library
libwrap0:i386                       i386   Wietse Venema's TCP wrappers library
libx11-6:i386                       i386   X11 client-side library
libx11-xcb1:i386                    i386   Xlib/XCB interface library
libx264-155:i386                    i386   x264 video coding library
libx265-179:i386                    i386   H.265/HEVC video stream encoder (shared library)
libxau6:i386                        i386   X11 authorisation library
libxcb-dri2-0:i386                  i386   X C Binding, dri2 extension
libxcb-dri3-0:i386                  i386   X C Binding, dri3 extension
libxcb-glx0:i386                    i386   X C Binding, glx extension
libxcb-present0:i386                i386   X C Binding, present extension
libxcb-randr0:i386                  i386   X C Binding, randr extension
libxcb-render0:i386                 i386   X C Binding, render extension
libxcb-shm0:i386                    i386   X C Binding, shm extension
libxcb-sync1:i386                   i386   X C Binding, sync extension
libxcb-xfixes0:i386                 i386   X C Binding, xfixes extension
libxcb1:i386                        i386   X C Binding
libxcomposite1:i386                 i386   X11 Composite extension library
libxcursor1:i386                    i386   X cursor management library
libxdamage1:i386                    i386   X11 damaged region extension library
libxdmcp6:i386                      i386   X11 Display Manager Control Protocol library
libxext6:i386                       i386   X11 miscellaneous extension library
libxfixes3:i386                     i386   X11 miscellaneous 'fixes' extension library
libxi6:i386                         i386   X11 Input extension library
libxinerama1:i386                   i386   X11 Xinerama extension library
libxkbcommon0:i386                  i386   library interface to the XKB compiler - shared library
libxml2:i386                        i386   GNOME XML library
libxpm4:i386                        i386   X11 pixmap library
libxrandr2:i386                     i386   X11 RandR extension library
libxrender1:i386                    i386   X Rendering Extension client library
libxshmfence1:i386                  i386   X shared memory fences - shared library
libxslt1.1:i386                     i386   XSLT 1.0 processing library - runtime library
libxss1:i386                        i386   X11 Screen Saver extension library
libxv1:i386                         i386   X11 Video extension library
libxvidcore4:i386                   i386   Open source MPEG-4 video codec (library)
libxxf86vm1:i386                    i386   X11 XFree86 video mode extension library
libzstd1:i386                       i386   fast lossless compression algorithm
libzvbi0:i386                       i386   Vertical Blanking Interval decoder (VBI) - runtime files
mesa-va-drivers:i386                i386   Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386             i386   Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386            i386   Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386             i386   Generic OpenCL ICD Loader
va-driver-all:i386                  i386   Video Acceleration (VA) API -- driver metapackage
vdpau-driver-all:i386               i386   Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix (driver metapackage)
wine32:i386                         i386   Windows API implementation - 32-bit binary loader
zlib1g:i386                         i386   compression library - runtime
```

Are all these packages still relevant? Do they have amd64 equivalent? If Ubuntu 20.04 has dropped i386 support, why weren't these packages removed in the installation process?

**Edit**

What prompted me to ask this question was `sudo apt update` outputting these two lines :

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Comment: @Terrance you are right, I did upgrade from `19.04` to `19.10` (last November) then to `20.04` (this morning), but the point remains, these repositories have indeed been disabled, thus why I'm asking the question.

Comment: It might help if you [edit] your question and describe the actual warning/error from apt that indicates the packages _can't be upgraded_ as you've stated. Most of these are almost certainly available in the focal archive.

Comment: Upon a quick check in a 20.04 VM I have right now, I only checked a few of those, and they can be installed without removing the AMD64 version of the package.  `sudo apt install glib-networking:i386` would install the `i386` version alongside of the `amd64` version that is already there.  Sometimes those `i386` versions get installed with other packages like `wine` or `steam`.  But I do agree with dobey above to get the actual error message that shows that.  There might only be a few of them that cannot be upgraded that could be 3rd party.

Comment: @Terrance edited the question

Comment: Yeah, those 2 can be skipped as they can be reinstalled easily if need be.  Plus, neither one of those repositories have supported i386 for a long time now.  I have normally had to add `[arch=amd64]` right after `deb` in the repository lines for those to no longer get that message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x)