# Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates, dpkg

Latest Edit: Fixed!

First Edit: Someone tried to identify this post as a [possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x). The commands that were posted there are not working for me, which I stated below. Also, I do not believe this is from Google Chrome. I don't even have Chrome installed.

So, I know this has already been asked, but the commands don't seem to work for me. I don't know how to fix this error. I am on Ubuntu 20.10. The full error message is posted below.

```
Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I have already tried to use the command below to fix this, with no luck.

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Hopefully someone here knows how to fix this.

Comment: Nope. I edited the question to and provided extra info.

Comment: @LiterallyJohnny the error is from mono-project repo not google-chrome repo. Check in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/...` . that's not a command line, you have to edit the files.

Comment: @user.dz Fixed! Thanks for this.

Comment: You welcome LiterallyJohnny.