# dotnet-sdk-5.0 not found on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, dotnet

I'm currently using the net core 3.1 and want to upgrade it to 5.0. I tried following this guide from I[nstall the .NET SDK or the .NET Runtime on Ubuntu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004:)

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

but looks like the `dotnet-sdk-5.0` is not found

```
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-5.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-5.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-5.0'
```

A quick cache dump only returns old versions:

```
➜  ~ sudo apt-cache dump | grep dotnet-sdk
Package: dotnet-sdk-2.2
Package: dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

It works just fine for my laptop also running 20.04, but not on this desktop. Weird. Did I miss anything?

Comment: What does `uname -m; cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list` return? Did you encounter any error while running `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: It was
`x86_64
# deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/19.04/prod disco main # disabled on upgrade to focal`
From this I could guess that my problem was probably due to the fact that I upgraded to 20.04 from 19.04. So I manually add one for 20.04 by `sudo apt-add-repository https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error on Ubuntu. Running these solved the problem:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/21.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update; \
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I was able to, finally, install version 5 by adding the repo for 20.04

```
sudo apt-add-repository https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod
```

While the installation successful, there were still some errors

```
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Comment: See [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/866901/816190) and [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/q/741410/816190).

Answer (score 0):

You may be a case listed under [APT troubleshooting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#apt-troubleshooting), and that is a possible difference between your laptop and desktop.

Try for instance the instructions to [Install the .NET SDK or the .NET Runtime with Snap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap).

It is also useful if you post details on your laptop and desktop (brand, model, etc.)

**Related**:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZh2O8IVb7U

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu Jammy 22.04.

You need to install .Net version 6 in Ubuntu Jammy, because version 5 is not present in the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-6.0
```