# apt error: repository doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: apt, package-management

When I run `sudo apt update` got this message:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt hirsute-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

this is output of `dpkg --get-selections | awk '/i386/{print $1}'`

```
gcc-11-base:i386
libc6:i386
libcap2:i386
libcom-err2:i386
libcrypt1:i386
libdbus-1-3:i386
libgamemode0:i386
libgamemodeauto0:i386
libgcc-s1:i386
libgcrypt20:i386
libgpg-error0:i386
libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
libidn2-0:i386
libk5crypto3:i386
libkeyutils1:i386
libkrb5-3:i386
libkrb5support0:i386
liblz4-1:i386
liblzma5:i386
libnsl2:i386
libnss-nis:i386
libnss-nisplus:i386
libssl1.1:i386
libsystemd0:i386
libtirpc3:i386
libunistring2:i386
libzstd1:i386
```

checked this directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, but there is nothing about postgres to change it from something like this : `REPOCONFIG="deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main"` to : `REPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main"`

output of `rep -r postgresql /etc/apt --include=*.list` :

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt hirsute-pgdg main
```

Comment: What is the output of `grep -r postgresql /etc/apt --include=*.list` ?

Comment: @N0rbert this is the output `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt hirsute-pgdg main`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x)

Comment: @nobody No, I tried everything in that question but not worked. The answer from _N0rbert_ worked and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` file to change

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt hirsute-pgdg main
```

to

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt hirsute-pgdg main
```

by `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Then update package lists by `sudo apt-get update` and so on.

Comment: now it's working without any error message, thank you .

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is not showing a pgdg.list.

Comment: @GriMa the `.list` file depends on the repository that raises the problem. Try `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` to compare the name of the `.list` files with the repository reported in the error.