# Skipping acquire of configured file 'https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: package-management, 32-bit, postgresql

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I am a bit fresh user for ubuntu. after installing postgresql 14, and I ran `sudo apt update`. Then it says

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Already tested  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` changed from

```
# deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

to

```
# deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

but still the message shows up

Comment: UPDATE: Solved! The file was like this `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main # deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main` then I changed to `deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main # deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main` Then it worked!

Comment: Consider posting the details of your solution as an *answer*. This will be most helpful for future visitors with the same question. Comments are temporary in nature and answers allow for better formatting so the text can be copy/pasted more easily. You can also come back in a few days and accept your own answer. Thanks for contributing to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x)

Answer (score 1):

The file was like this

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
# deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

then I changed

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main 
# deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

then it worked. It seems it is important to add [arch=amd64] and put "s" in https