# Microsoft repository creates mess. How to fix?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

For my work I need to install some ms packages, so I added the repository (following [these instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/linux-package-repository-for-microsoft-software#ubuntu)):

```
curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
sudo apt-add-repository https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod
sudo apt-get update
```

The `apt update` gives me the output below. Does anybody know what is wrong and how I can fix this?

```
[...]
Hit:20 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-nl) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-nl) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
```

Comment: These are only warnings, nothing is wrong. To get rid of the warnings, comment out line 3 in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list`.

Comment: @Jos - But there is also another error. The first line says it's skipping something. How can I solve that?

Comment: See the accepted answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x