# N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages', ... 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease'

Tags: 20.04, deb, mono

Full Error

```
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I edited `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list`

From

`deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main`

to

`deb [arch=i386] https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main`

But now get error

```
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

When I browse the package I can see the i386 package ???

https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/stable-focal/main/binary-i386/

What stupid thing am I doing wrong ? many thanks

Comment: `uname -m`
`x86_64`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x)

Answer (score 2):

This repository does not provide 32-bit packages. Its [Packages](https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/stable-focal/main/binary-i386/Packages) has zero size.

So you have to replace `[arch=i386]` by `[arch=amd64]` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list` and then run `sudo apt-get update` again.

Answer (score 0):

I only put [arch=amd64] in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list` and then ran `sudo apt update` .
Because the default version taken is [arch=i386] even if there is not specified in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list`.