# Problem with Apt fetching updates

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, google-chrome

When I tried to update `apt`'s local package index, I am getting an error

```
% sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
...
lots or repositories
...
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com .....
Fetched 2,628 kB in 34s (75.7 kB/s)
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_NZ
    Fetched 2,628 kB in 34s (75.7 kB/s)

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So trying to trace `apt`'s flow of actions, I see

file: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` contains

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Im guessing this is what tells `apt` to *try* get fresh package lists from `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/`.

Looking at the contents of the "failed "file: `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release` hosted on googles repo server:

contains:

```
Origin: Google, Inc.
Label: Google
Suite: stable
Codename: stable
Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 22:43:39 +0000
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Description: Google chrome-linux repository.
MD5Sum:
 89704f9af9e6ccd87c192de11ba4c511 145 main/binary-amd64/Release
 43ceb3a785b6dd436c53e9dbde008599 4164 main/binary-amd64/Packages
 7ea2e6a029b4fedb4c1518f6465e577a 961 main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
 64235650d3cd442717b11560da225787 1197 main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2
SHA1:
 153199d8f866350b7853365a4adc95ee687603dd 145 main/binary-amd64/Release
 02ca738529f7cc2effb3f4da95316726c15afd6f 4164 main/binary-amd64/Packages
 8ecf917c5c7a93c9b3afb24a3b961d6bcd88bc33 961 main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
 b7756eaa63557380b74b15a379cb49f2d4dfc5b6 1197 main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2
```

- What is the purpose of this file? `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release`
- How can I fix this error?

I will update this post if anyone needs anymore info

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error).

Comment: I had to add the [arch=amd64] to mine in order for it to work, and I am running 64bit as well.

Comment: @Terrance Im not sure I understand. where did you add [arch=64] ?

Comment: I edited my response, but in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` file, right after the word `deb` I had to add `[arch=amd64]` just like that answer says to do.

Comment: If you copy and paste `sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list" "/opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome"` into a terminal window it should fix it in the files needed.

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could help you out.  =)