# Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages - Chrome

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, google-chrome, dpkg

I recently noticed while installing some packages and using the command `apt-get update`  that I ran into the following error:

```
Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  
Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

As mentioned in [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error-solved) recent question on Ask Ubuntu, Chrome will no longer be supported by 32 bit systems, however I am currently running 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04, with `libc6:i386` `libncurses5:i386` `libstdc++6:i386` installed for 32 bit application support.

Am I seeing this error because **dpkg** is looking for the i386 packages as a result of the aforementioned install of `libc6:i386` `libncurses5:i386` `libstdc++6:i386`?

How do I resolve this error?

**EDIT -** (I was not able to resolve this question with simply updating Chrome as mentioned in the other thread, and not all the information in the other answer was present at the time I posted this).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

1. Open a new Terminal window and run the following command:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   ```
2. In the text file that opens edit the file so that the line reads:

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
   ```

   The only addition you need to make is entering the [amd64] architecture after `deb` but preceding the `http`. Do not edit or replace any other text in this file.
3. Hit Save. Close the Gedit window.

   Now return to the Terminal and refresh your package list by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   The 'failed to fetch' APT error should no longer appear.

   To prevent the above change being lost, `[arch=amd64]` needs to be added to the configuration that generates the file edited above:
4. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo gedit  /opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome
   ```
5. In the text file that opens search for deb and once again edit the file so that deb http becomes:

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64] http
   ```

   Do not edit or replace any other text in this file.
6. Hit Save. Close the Gedit window.

Sources:

- [How To Fix The (Annoying) ‘Failed to Fetch’ Chrome apt Error](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu)
- [Failed To Fetch` Google Chrome Repository After Google Dropped Support For Its Browser On Linux 32bit ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html)

Comment: I think people would recommend `pkexec gedit` or `sudo -H gedit` instead of `sudo gedit`.

Comment: And the post you mentioned has answers that cover this (and in a better way).

Comment: feel free to type out your own answer if you think you can help others better than I did @muru.

Comment: Why should I type out anything, when another user has handled it excellently?

Comment: perhaps to be helpful (like i was trying to do.. i was just trying to help). Do you think it wise to chastise users that make an effort to help just because someone else did it better? @muru

Comment: I do think it wise to avoid fragmenting information. For example, the other post has been updated to note that this is no longer necessary - upgrading Chrome will fix this (and the error shown does not prevent you from upgrading Chrome). Your answer does not mention this. And all I said was that the other post covers this better - if you take that as chastisement, you already feel you have done something wrong, which is not my problem.

Comment: My answer did not include that info because upgrading Chrome did not resolve the issue. If it is that simple, feel free to answer the question with that information in the answer if you think it will help users better.

Comment: FWIW, I like this answer better than the cited source. Short and to the point, not wasting my time.

Comment: It won't work. The friendly source file header says: ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.

Comment: @Uqbar   Im ot sure why you're saying this won't work as it is has worked for lots of people, myself included

Comment: @KalamalkaKid For two reasons. 1. It doesn't work for me: every updates resets the source file. 2. Google says otherwise in the source file itself. That's enough for me to say "it doesn't work".

Comment: @Uqbar you might want to avoid using absolutes. Try using statements that verify your own experience without contradicting those of others. You might have said "this didnt work for me", etc as it has clearly worked for others.

Comment: @kalamalka kid I told "for me" meaning "in my very case". Then, have you read the content of the files in question? I don't think so. The workaround only works once per upgrade. Try it!

Comment: First three instructions can be replaced with a one-liner: `echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list > /dev/null`

Comment: Had a similar issue with webdesigner: `Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb/dists/stable/Release`...`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-webdesigner.list` - added `[arch=amd64]` as mentined above = issue fixed

Comment: Google Earth Pro is another one that is still acting up.  When it happens I     sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth-pro.list"