# Problem with apt-get update wrong source list from google-chrome

Tags: 15.10

When I try to run `apt-get update`, I get an error

`Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release             Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)`

How can I fix it? I don't remember chrome version installed.

Comment: Google is no longer maintaining Chrome for 32-bit operating systems. If you want to have the latest security updates, you need to use Chromium or Firefox or get a 64-bit computer.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743814/unable-to-find-expected-entry-main-binary-i386-packages-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has stopped supporting Google Chrome on 32-bit Linux.

Users running a 32bit Linux distribution are advised to stop using Google Chrome because, while it will continue to work, it will no longer receive any updates (including no security fixes).

For 64 Bit systems, you need to run this command in terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>   + <kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"
```

For 32 Bit systems, you need to run this command in terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>   + <kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome
```

Comment: Can I do this action with unstable version, right?

Comment: You can give it a try.