# can't upgrade from google chrome 45 to 50. Says, Unable to find expected entry

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, updates, google-chrome

i have looked at some of the solutions here, but nothing worked:
[Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages - Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743814/unable-to-find-expected-entry-main-binary-i386-packages-chrome) and [No more updates for Google Chrome | apt-get update error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error).

i'm currently running `Chrome 45.0.2454 (64-bit)` on my `Ubuntu 14.04` 64-bit box.

I have been trying to upgrade chrom to version 50 for several hours, but nothing seems to work.Tried doing it using Software Centre as well but to no avail (nothing happens when I click "Install" as mentioned in the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error) as well). When i try to upgrade Chrome to 50, using `sudo apt-get update` i get,

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file).
```

i have added `[arch=amd64]` into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`, but when i do `sudo apt-get update` i get the same error message.

my google-chrome.list file looks as below now:

cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

How do i upgrade my chrome 45 to 50?

**few more information to help someone help me:**

sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
google-chrome-stable is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libkactivities-models1 mysql-server-core-5.5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 51 not to upgrade.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: Is this a 32 vs 64 bit issue? Apt tries to fetch 'main/binary-i386/Packages' which sounds like 32 instead of 64bit

Comment: my current chrome version is 64 bit and my machine is 64 bit. does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is downloading and installing latest chrome (.deb) from [Google](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) manually.

After having downloading it you have to either installing it by doubleclicking the .deb file or executing

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/local/chrome.deb
```

Manually installing the deb should as well add a new entry to your sources for later upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

My **chrome** said that *google* will not support anymore *old kernels* with updates 
Maybe thats why it doesn't work!
Try to get the ***latest kernel*** version and than try again.