# Ubuntu 14.04 Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages'

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, updates, sudo

After searching and trying some of the solutions which are already there on Stack. I am still getting following errors after updating by command

sudo apt-get update

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried to change the source.list in /etc/apt/source.list to

https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/txt/trusty/sources_ea1ee6370a7250187bd9b0b7da2b433794869b25.txt

using Ubuntu Sources List Generator in

https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

This answer didnt solved my answer since its just for chrome
 [Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages - Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743814/unable-to-find-expected-entry-main-binary-i386-packages-chrome)[duplicate] 1

I have been trying to understand where I am going wrong but still I couldn't make it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i386`, not `1386`.

Comment: Ok!! I guess that was the mistake...Thank You!

Comment: But still I am facing the same issue. ( Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file )

Comment: Exactly the same output? What's the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`?

Comment: i386
i386sudo
This is the output I am getting

Comment: solved the issue by removing i386sudo . Thanks muru