# apt-get update fail (file not found)

Tags: apt, updates

When I try to `apt-get update`, I have this error:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/flareget-amd64/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
.
.
.
E: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
```

Comment: Packages on launchpad are (generally) maintained by volunteers - you could contact [upubuntu](http://www.upubuntu.com/) to see if they are going to maintain that package, or you could download a deb file from the package from [https://flareget.com/download](https://flareget.com/download)

Comment: i can't install any package i have the same problem, how can i fix the problem ?

thnak you :)

Comment: Please review [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858374/apt-get-update-missing-release-file) for instructions about removing the entry to the missing release file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all you have to do is go to "Software & Updates" tab "Other software" and uncheck or delete the lines for these ppa.