# 'Update Information Is Outdated' after running bleachbit

Tags: apt, package-management

Yesterday I ran on 14.04 bleachbit with almost all options except for memory, (and now I understand it's not the most correct way of using bleachbit), and the program ended when I interrupted through command line in the end.

Now, when I open software-updater, it loads the software list but then warns me with "failed to download repository information, check your internet connection", yet after I've clicked on settings and closed again without doing anything, the updater could actually continue normally, either telling me everything is up to date or downloading/installing the updates.

Meanwhile, I also get error notification regularly, telling me "update information is outdated" and that I need to click on show updates, which goes back to the software-updater.

I believe there haven't been still many other "harms" done to the system that I just haven't discovered yet (e.g. find also has become slow, although I guess it's because the cached files were gone). What I can do about it to minimize the damage?

Thanks in advance!

The output of sudo apt-get update is: (I replace http and https into ' ' and 's ')

```
Ign  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Get:1  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65,9 kB]          
Ign  dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign  extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Hit  dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit  extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit  dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit  dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit  extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                           
Get:2  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [262 kB]        
Hit  extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                             
Hit  extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                      
Get:3  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65,9 kB]
Get:4  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5.352 B] 
Hit  extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:5  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [150 kB]    
Get:6  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5.943 B] 
Get:7  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [713 kB] 
Get:8  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [106 kB]         
Get:9  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15,9 kB]
Get:10  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [339 kB]
Ign  extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign  extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:11  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13,2 kB]
Get:12  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [692 kB] 
Get:13  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4.035 B] 
Get:14  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [33,3 kB]   
Get:15  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15,6 kB]
Get:16  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [340 kB]
Get:17  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [2.767 B] 
Get:18  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13,6 kB]
Get:19  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [361 kB]
Get:20  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [431 kB] 
Get:21  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7.227 B]
Get:22  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3.699 B]
Get:23  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [181 kB]
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                     
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Get:24  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [13,0 kB]
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Get:25  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [124 kB]
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Get:26  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4.990 B]
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en   
Get:27  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [404 kB]
Ign  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US             
Ign  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US       
Ign  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US        
Ign  de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Get:28  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [12,7 kB]
Get:29  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [124 kB]
Hit  s packagecloud.io jessie InRelease           
Get:30  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [5.164 B]
Hit  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en   
Hit  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit  s packagecloud.io jessie/main amd64 Packages
Hit  security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit  s packagecloud.io jessie/main i386 Packages
Get:31  s packagecloud.io jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign  s packagecloud.io jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign  s packagecloud.io jessie/main Translation-en
Fetched 4.514 kB in 5s (876 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch  dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Please tell me output of `grep -R --include '*.list' 'dl.google.com' /etc/apt/` - it will tell us where the line about Google Chrome is which doesn't work any more, so that we can remove or disable it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No more updates for Google Chrome | apt-get update error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error)

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-unstable.list:deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

Comment: However, if this had always been a problem, why am I only getting this warning since yesterday?

Comment: Because Google a few months back that they would remove the repo in March http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued . The reason likely is they then don't have to look after both a 32bit and a 64bit package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you see in the output is that Google Chrome is no longer available for 32 bit architectures. Therefore they removed the repository from their server and you can't update your lists from there again.

To solve the problems, simply remove the list entries from your configuration by deleting the file they're in:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome*
```

Then also get rid of your outdated Google Chrome browser and install the similar open source browser Chromium.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll follow it but can someone perhaps explain to me why this warning wasn't showing up until I used bleachbit? It's not the first ubuntu system where I notice such thing happening. By the way, I used to use chromium some years ago, but it had some problems with rendering special characters like Chinese etc

Comment: Maybe just a coincidence and Bleachbit has nothing to do with it. it could be just the first time you updated your software list since Chrome 32bit got discontinued, that's not too long ago...

Comment: Also if this answer solved your problem, you should consider accepting it by clicking the grey tick symbol on the left. You can take the [tour] and learn how this site works in only two minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that BleachBit really damaged your system. The operations that it does are generally safe---unless you need your cache, temporary files, etc. Without better information, it seems the correlation with the error message is a coincidence.

Your next step is troubleshooting the updater, so I suggest in a terminal run `sudo apt-get update` and read the messages. Is the error for one source or all sources? Do you have custom/third-party sources? Maybe the mirror for one the sources is down.

Also check that your disk partitions are not full.

Finally, make sure you download the latest [BleachBit cleaner](http://www.bleachbit.org) because Ubuntu repositories often have ancient versions.

Comment: Hmm, I think judging from the ooutput, I do not have third-party sources, and since the error was for one or more sources, I guess it's possible that one mirror is down. However, this doesn't explain why after clicking on settings then closing it, the updates can continue normally. My disk is far from being full, and I'd like to know what might have happened since I've manually interrupted bleachbit while it was not responding

Comment: You have a 3rd party repo from google to get 32bit Chrome and you also have installed Debian repositories. The one making problems is the google one. It's because they stopped support for 32bit Chrome, so probably the repository got simply removed. Delete that entry from your sources lists.