# Why is the update information outdated as of 2016-03-10 in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: updates, 15.10, update-manager

I have an exclamation point saying "The update information is outdated" which has appeared today (2016-10-03), and when I ran the update manager I got an error message that it failed to download information.  (By the way, there is nothing wrong with my internet connection.)

[image]

---

The command: `sudo apt-get update` gives me this error message after an attempt to update:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Google Chrome seems to be giving me a hard time?

Comment: Run `sudo apt get update` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html) of this solution:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"
```

then update with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and everything will be fine.

---

Long explanation: Google Chrome packages put automatically their repository file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.
Since the beginning of March the 32 bit (`i386`) repository has been disabled - see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/724093/29595) for more details.
Unfortunately they forgot to update the information on their source file!
The problem was then solved since version 49.0.2623.87 of Google Chrome, but for previous versions the above procedure is a workaround to this problem.

Comment: Yes good call, fixed my crome - that dumped the error yesterday, but I didn't  manage to report this error before this post

Comment: yep. Works like a charm. Cheers.

Comment: Great to hear! :)

Comment: is this related to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/743912/ubuntu-chrome-and-firefox-with-untrusted-certification-authorities ?

Comment: @lapsidecor no, this is a different problem.

Comment: @dadexix86 thank you, this works also for me, but the problem appears again and again every week. Is there a way to fix it permanently?

Comment: @WoDoSc which version of Google Chrome are you using? And which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @dadexix86 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit), but actually I just noticed that the problem is not about Chrome but about Google Webdesigner. It was exactly the same problem with exactly the same fix (to re-apply every X days). Since I don't need the Webdesigner I just removed that package, but it is wired that at every update, the problem re-appears.

Comment: Remove all the google repositories and software, and then add them again one by one until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Ubuntu 14.04.3 I also had to update:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
```

Which had:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

with:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

OR just terminal:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list"
```

Same issue with **google-webdesigner**

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-webdesigner.list"
```

NEW FILE:
    `$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-webdesigner.list
    deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb/ stable`
main

PREVIOUS VERSION:
    `$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-webdesigner.list.save 
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb/ stable main`

& now an new error:
    `W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems`

Just remove:
    `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list`