# Updating Google Chrome gives sources.list error

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following error:

> W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

How do I correct this error?

Comment: You can find everything here -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error/724170#724170 ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because chrome has dropped support for its 32bit variant on Linux.You might want to shift to another browser. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued

[Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) is your best alternative, considering how similar it is to Chrome.

In the meanwhile, you can use one of the following URLs to fix the issue
.

- http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html
- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu