# (Apt)itude-get is broken

Tags: updates, update-manager

When I try to update:

```
sudo apt-get update
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. Also every time that I get new updates from Software & Updates it fails. How can I work to fix this issue?
```

And I'm not sure how to fix it using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error) solution.

Comment: Chrome will no longer support 32bit system. The solution in the mentioned link is to force chrome to just look for 64bit version in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal `CTRL + ALT + T` and use this code:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"
```

Google has dropped support for 32-bit system. Your problem is about that. You can use that code for fix this error.

But please search your problem first, if it doesn't exist, you can open a new question.

Comment: Thanks, the sudo apt-get update problem was solved, but I still have problem with Software & Updates program that is giving fails the updates!

Comment: you can search these fails on Google or here. Also, if you're still getting same error (google chrome error), you should use my answer again.