# How to get rid of this post "requires installation of untrusted packages"?

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

i know that there are have been some answers on this issue. But i have already tried some of them and without success.

I don't know why but every time when i turn my laptop on i got this message.

Last way that i have tried [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1878602).

What i am doing wrong?

[image]

output of sudo apt-get update

```
aleksey@aleksey:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for aleksey: 
Ign http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                   
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources             
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64   Packages      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages             
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist InRelease                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse   Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Get:1 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release.gpg [490 B]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                        
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg [316 B]                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release                           
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release                           
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse   Translation-en    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen amd64   Packages/DiffIndex    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-ru                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-ru              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen i386   Packages/DiffIndex     
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com trusty InRelease                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-ru              
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-ru                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Sources                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Ign http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Ign http://il.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Get:3 https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-ru                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-ru                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-ru
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en_US   
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US     
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-ru        
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-ru      
Hit http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen amd64 Packages              
Hit http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen i386 Packages               
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen Translation-en_US           
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen Translation-en              
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen Translation-ru              
Fetched 806 B in 9s (84 B/s)                                                   
W: GPG error: http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release: The   following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not   available: NO_PUBKEY 9ECBEC467F0CEB10
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following  signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:  NO_PUBKEY 0F678A01569113AE
W: Failed to fetch  http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find   expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong   sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
aleksey@aleksey:~$
```

output of sudo apt-get upgrade

```
aleksey@aleksey:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer  required:
calligra-l10n-ru kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-he kde-l10n-ru
linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
coreutils google-chrome-stable initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin  libtiff5
libtiff5:i386 mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools nodejs openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre
openjdk-7-jre-headless
15 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 230 MB of archives.
After this operation, 858 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org- tools
mongodb-org
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] 
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
aleksey@aleksey:~$
```

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: And http://askubuntu.com/q/65911/158442 and http://askubuntu.com/q/724093/158442

Comment: sorry but i rookie in ubuntu and i don't understand completely. First link about "How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY" ... Second link about "404 mistake" and third link about "google chrome" but how it connect with my issue? If you know could you please say me a command which i should enter to fix my problem? Thanks so much

Comment: Look at the end of the `apt-get update` ouput. You'll see two GPG errors about `NO_PUBKEY`, an error about Google Chrome's repos, and two 404 errors about a PPA. Three different sets of errors, three different solutions. See the linked posts.

Comment: unfortunately it is not helped me(( i don't know why(( Could you help me in TeamViewer or other remote control program fix this bug?