# Can't launch google chrome on ubuntu 15.10 install via PPA

Tags: 15.10, google-chrome

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop, so I want to install Google Chrome. First time, it was installed by Ubuntu Software Center which I downloaded deb file from official Google Chrome website, but it don't have any response when I launch the Google Chrome from terminal or search app by super key. I already tried to install by terminal via PPA:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

It still don't have any response.

I had tried to start app by terminal it didn't launch any thing and don't have any error like this.

[image]

ps. tell me if you want more details

Comment: By default google-chrome will only run under the normal user. Running as **root** is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Google Chrome from a terminal using the following method - open a terminal and execute:

```
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list  
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

In case you receive an [apt-get update error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error/724170#724170) ... you can ignore it - once Google Chrome is installed, the settings get overwritten and the error will not occur and be displayed from now on anymore.

Launch Google Chrome as a normal user and not as root like you did according to the screenshot.

**Update addressing your response that you still cannot launch Google Chrome web browser:**

Make sure that you are logged in to the normal user account and do everything as a normal user.

1.) Delete the folder `/home/your-user-name/.config/google-chrome`.

2.) Uninstall Google Chrome: `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`.

3.) Reinstall Google Chrome: `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`.

Comment: It's didn't work. don't have any response

Comment: I'm installed on ubuntu 64-bit

Comment: @DrNutsu : Please provide the output from -> dpkg --get-selections | grep google-chrome

Comment: `google-chrome-stable    install`

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work anymore (assuming it once did).

Answer (score 0):

You can download .deb file of chrome from https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html
And install directly

Comment: I already tried, but it's didn't work