# The following packages have been kept back : google-chrome-stable

Tags: package-management, google-chrome

Today when i tried to update, i got a message that there was 1 upgrade to be made, so i did a `sudo apt-get upgrade` and got this message:

`The following packages have been kept back: google-chrome-stable`

So i looked around and it said that `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` would fix the problem, but it didn't. Then i opened Synaptic, went `Fix Broken Packages`, and still nothing.

I finally searched for google-chrome-stable in Synaptic, found the packages and when i marked them for upgrade i got this:

[image]

How can i fix this?

**I should note that i am using Ubuntu 12.04 - 64 bit**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 does not receive updates for Google Chrome, more information you can find here :
[The support for Google Chrome on 32-bit Linux systems and Ubuntu 12.04 ended in March 2016.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error/724170#724170)
You should uninstall Google Chrome mainly, because you do not get security updates anymore !

To remove Google Chrome open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
```

To remove the Google Chrome repository execute :

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

To remove all the configuration files delete this folder : `/home/user/.config/google-chrome`

Check whether there is another Google `.list` file in the `sources.list.d` folder and in case there is - remove it as well. Alternatively you can install the `chromium-browser`, on which the Google Chrome web browser is built or you wait a few days and install the new Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Great Answer! I just didn't know Chrome stopped recieving updates for 64 bit aswell. Guess Chroimium would do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `dist-upgrade` command cleaned out your repository list, disabling the outdated `google-chrome.list`.

**This can be fixed by reinstalling the latest version of Chrome**

Google Chrome for Ubuntu can be downloaded from Google.  At present, the 64bit version is the only one available.

The error is resolved by installing the latest version from Google.

The download link is http://www.google.com/chrome.  The official link can also be found with a google search of [download chrome](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=g0PtWrSQE420ggfo3rKwCQ&q=download+chrome&oq=download+chrome&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i20i263k1l2j0l8.25581.33078.0.33618.35.23.7.0.0.0.181.2861.0j22.23.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..5.30.3256.6..35i39k1j0i131k1j0i131i20i263k1j0i20i263i264k1j0i20i264k1j0i131i20i264k1.191.seDfdXOu0fk).