# Where can I download the chrome i386 deb file?

Tags: google-chrome, 32-bit, deb

Where can I download the Chrome i386 deb file? Google does not allow installing Chrome 32 bit from its web anymore. I am running xubuntu 15.10

Comment: You can't; it's discontinued (unless you want to go with an old version with known vulnerabilities). See “[No more updates for Google Chrome | apt-get update error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error).”

Answer (score 11):

That's because Chrome 32-bit is no longer supported on Ubuntu. Chrome is also no longer supported on Ubuntu 12.04 with either 32-bit or 64-bit.

It is not a good idea to install the 32-bit version of Chrome on Ubuntu, as it no longer receives updates of any kind. That means an you'll have an outdated and insecure browser as soon as you install.

If you can't get 64-bit Ubuntu, you'll have to install Chromium instead.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

http://betanews.com/2015/11/30/google-killing-chrome-for-32-bit-linux/

Comment: Chromium is almost an exact duplicate of Chrome, just with a community working the development and bugs (which is actually quicker in some cases than Chrome).

Comment: There is no `--dump-dom` or `--headless` in Chromium on Ubuntu 14 LTS.