# apt error google chrome 32-bit

Tags: software-installation

My PC has Ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit). During the installation of skype it's showing this error:

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:                 
1397BC53640DB551
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not Skype-related -- it has to do with Google Chrome. The 32-bit version of Chrome is [no longer supported](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued) by Google and has been removed, thus you see an error accessing that repo.

This means Chrome no longer receives important security updates, and you should consider switching browsers (or using a 64-bit OS).

---

**Edit:** see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/724170/16835) for more detailed info.