# Software updates and Synaptic package manager problems

Tags: apt, updates, downloads

Synaptic package manager fails and provides this error:

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release
Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Synaptic package manager:

```
E: The value 'trusty' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

How do I correct this problem?

Comment: I think you are getting the first set of errors error because Google has completely dropped all support for 32-bit versions of Google Chrome. Your system is trying to retrieve the i386 version of the Google Chrome software repository, but Google no longer provides it (I believe they only supply the amd64 version now). I'm not sure about the cause of the second set of error messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No more updates for Google Chrome 32-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-32-bit)