# Netflix on Firefox / Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to watch Netflix on Firefox 50.0 on my Ubuntu 12.04. Netflix keeps asking for Silverlight and HTML 5. I tried to download Chrome but found out much to my dismay that Chrome installation package for 32 bit Ubuntu has been discontinued. My Ubuntu is a 32 bit. So what do I do now? Please please help.

Comment: try this post: http://askubuntu.com/a/724170/595510

Answer (score -1):

You may try to install Chrome on Ubuntu, but, it is not advisable. If possible, upgrade to 64 bit Ubuntu. However, as an immediate solution to your problem will be installing Chromium. It is an open-source version of Chrome. In the terminal type:

**sudo apt-get install chromium-browser**

You can also install it through Ubuntu Software Center.

Many other browsers (like Opera) are based on Chromium. If your Netflix working has been stymied only by the lack of Chrome on the system, this should do the trick. I myself, am using Chromium as an alternative to Chrome for years.

Comment: Not really an answer. Chrome comes with the updated Flash required for Netflix, Chromium doesn't.

Comment: That's correct. I am sorry for that. But, I think that can be installed easily on Ubuntu.

Comment: So the correct answer would have to be *how* to install what's missing and that wouldn't even require Chromium (check the duplicated flag comment above).