# chrome aw snap issue

Tags: 14.04, unity, google-chrome

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and chrome 39.0.2171.95 version. The system is 32 bit. I am getting an aw-snap error in all the cases of chrome.

I have tried to remove and reinstall the chrome but same error occurring again and again.

I am not able to open

```
chrome://version/
chrome://settings/
chrome://appcache-internals/
```

etc
chrome://*

All the pages are giving me an aw-snap error.You can see here

[image]

When I click on suggestion link which is on aw-snap error page, it is giving me manifest file is missing or unreadable.

Thanks

Comment: Google Chrome is not supported on 32 bit Linux systems anymore ... you can read about everything here -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error/724170#724170 ! :)

Comment: But do you think that is the case of error?

Comment: You are using completely outdated and unsupported software ... sooner or later this most likely will lead to various problems. Please choose one of the options given in my linked answer. :)

Comment: Yeah, i will try your suggested option though I don't understand that how outdated software give me an error?

Comment: *"The system is 32 bit"* - Well, that's probably the source of your problem. Google doesn't support 32-bit Chrome for Linux anymore, and so you've installed an outdated version.

Comment: yeah but outdated version don't create such issue, it just stop the update,if i am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Google has discontinued the 32-bit version of Chrome for Linux. Using Chrome on those system is a security risk. I suggest installing Chromium web browser (*chromium-browser*) from the default Ubuntu repositories as an alternative. Chromium web browser is an open-source version of Chrome.

Another alternative to Chrome is to tell your users of systems in the field to start using Firefox instead.

Comment: But i have more than thousands of systems on the field so right now unable to change

Comment: I should add that there are a lot of obsolete/untrusted versions of Google Chrome 32-bit for Linux available online from untrusted sources, but the official word from Google is that Google Chrome 32-bit for Linux has been discontinued.

Comment: My code is specific to chrome only. that is the reason to stick with chrome and trying to solve the issue.