# Old version of google-chrome starts even if newer is installed

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, google-chrome

For a while I haven't received Chrome updates on Kubuntu 16.04 64-bit . I did everything written here [No more updates for Google Chrome | apt-get update error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error)

When I execute

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

it writes

```
google-chrome-stable is already the newest version (56.0.2924.87-1).
```

but when I start chrome using

```
google-chrome-stable
```

the about:version page says

```
Google Chrome   49.0.2623.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Why is this?

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't have done "everything". The answer has several updates (with dates), Please edit and describe *exactly* what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird, but a restart solved the problem (after doing all things mentioned in the above question)

Comment: You might have some extension that kept Chrome running in the background.

Comment: Quite likely, because the gmail offline browser plugin was running!

Comment: In that case `killall chrome` would have had the same effect.