# I receive an error when trying to install Google Chrome

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, google-chrome

I am receiving a '403 forbidden error' when running `sudo apt-get update`.
I have used the following commands to add the Google Chrome repository :

Add key:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
```

Install package:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Output of apt-get update:

```
  sudo apt-get update 
  Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
  Ign http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
   Ign http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
   Err http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 172.217.26.206 80]                         
   Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
   Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
   Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
   Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
   Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
   Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
   Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
   Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
   Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
   Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
   Hit https://repo.skype.com stable InRelease                                    
   Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
   Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
   Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                   
   Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
   Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
   Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources             
   Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
   Hit https://repo.skype.com stable/main amd64 Packages                          
   Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources               
   Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
   Ign ftp://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg/main Translation-en                   
   W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 172.217.26.206 80]
   E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: And as the accepted answer reads: *This error is due to server and it is completely not your fault. Could be because of that repository was offline for maintenance.*

Comment: I am trying this more than a day

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something went wrong when you imported the key and added the repository - so start over from scratch by deleting the imported keys and removing the Google Chrome repository.

Search the imported Google keys : `apt-key adv --list-public-keys`
Delete the imported Google keys : `sudo apt-key del <key-ID>`
Remove the Google Chrome repo : `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

Additionally check the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file for old Google Chrome entries :
`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` In case that you find old entries, remove them.

Import the Google keys, add the Google Chrome repository and install Google Chrome this way :

```
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

Note that Google Chrome can only be installed on 64-bit Linux editions - [more information here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error/724170#724170).
The commands are slightly different to those ones you used, perhaps that was the reason why ...