# I have problem installing Google-Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to install Chrome. I go as far as the the installation window/button. when I click to install, it says "Installing" for 2 second and goes back to install button. Can anyone guide me in this? thanks,

Comment: You should try [Chromium](https://www.howtogeek.com/202825/what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-chromium-and-chrome/) :)

Comment: Will you append the output of this command-line to your question: `sudo uname -a && sudo lshw -class CPU | egrep width`

Comment: How are you trying to install? Are you from come countries which are blocked by google? (such as Iran?)

Comment: @SpasSpasov His problem is in installation of Google-Chrome. I don't find your comment relevant.

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha I just introduced Chromium to Iraj Y.

Comment: Mostafa, thank you for your response. No I am not in Iran and no restrictions. I have tried to download and install. The process goes through without any problems all the way to the "Install" window. When I click on the install button, the button changes to: "installing" for a couple of seconds and goes back to "Install" button. It does not even asks me to authenticate. So, I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Some times various window managers, do not prompt for the administrative(sudo) authentication. So try this, in your web browser, open a search dialog, and type download chrome.

This should take you to a location, that contains a download chrome button.
You will be prompted to chose between 64 but .deb (for Debian/Ubuntu) or 64 bit .rpm(for Fedora/openSUSE). Choose the .deb file.

And accept and install, the Google Chrome Terms of Service.

Choose to save the file.

Then drop to a Terminal Prompt, and navigate to where it was downloaded.
This location is typically, `/home/yourusername/Downloads`

type the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

The -i instructs dpkg to install the designated file.
The use of `./` informs dpkg, to use the current folder to find the specified file.

With `sudo` this prompt for your password, if you have sudoers privilege, it should provide the appropriate authentication and permit the installation to proceed.

Comment: dajavex, thank you for your response. As I mentioned, the install button does not work. So, I am trying to use the second option. I am using the following syntax and get an error message. sudo dpkg -i home/administrator/downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb    I would appreciate a little more help as this is my first day using linux. Thank you again

Comment: If the account was named administrator, then `/home/administrator/Downloads/.....`. Also remember, that filenames/pathnames within linux are case sensitive. Probably best, to navigate to the folder, where the file was downloaded. when dropped to a terminal prompt, you are in your 'home' folder..   type `cd Downloads`, then do an `ls -l` to confirm the file is present. The type `sudo dpkg -i ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Comment: dajavex, Thanks again for your help. I did do the CD command to downloads typed the command. Now I get the following    error "processing archive ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @IrajY          It seems like your hardware may not support that downloaded file, here is link that may provide an alternative to what I have provided. [Askubuntu post: no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error)