# Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Upgrade error

Tags: apt, package-management, 64-bit, update-manager

I just need a little help and direction with this. `sudo apt-get update` returns this [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7wYRMCnmAtVN0RJUW81Q2N0dlE/view?usp=sharing). 
My `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-GNOME 14.04.5 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20160803)]/ trusty main multiverse restricted universe
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

What can I do to resolve this? I do know my question is a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394653/ubuntu-64-bit-failed-to-fetch-file-binary-i386-packages-error-while-updat), all I need is a little direction/solution to this.

Comment: Probably just a temporary problem with the server. Try changing to the main one or other.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Wow, that was easy. Its only fair that you post that as an answer and I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just a temporary problem with the server. Try changing to the main one or other.