# how to build souce images for the ubuntu 22.04

Tags: source-code

Below is the souce images for the ubuntu 22.04, I want to how to build the source from below souce image to Ubuntu rootfs,  such as yocto or koji?

https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04/release/source/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build all my installed package from sources?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29856/how-to-build-all-my-installed-package-from-sources)